# "Copy path to clipboard" on Windows 64 bit

Tags: windows-server-2008, 64-bit

I had an excellent shell extension that enabled me to right click a file and copy its full path to the clipboard. It doesn't work on windows 64 bit. Does anyone have a utility that works under Windows server 2008 64 bit?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6):

This is built into Windows 2008 and Windows 7. Shift+Right Click on a file/folder and choose "Copy as Path".

Comment: Doesn't work with files on the network

Answer (score 2):

my favorite pathcopy tool:

https://pathcopycopy.codeplex.com/

[image]

Quote:

```
A Windows Explorer add-on that adds a contextual menu item on all files and 
folders allowing the user to copy the path in various formats. Idea copied 
from "Path Copy".

Works on Windows XP or later, both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.
```

Comment: thanks, solved my problems where the people still were on XP (and will be for a while...)